# Resource Manager to handle large scale workflows across heterogenous systems

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, nagios

I am looking for a open-source resource manager that can manage large scale workflows on a distributed computing environment.
I performed survey on TORQUE, SLURM, LOADLEVELER, SLURM is better than TORQUE in handling large nodes but in a single cluster. All are used for batch systems.
Condor is used for grid environments but provides coarse grained distributed parellization.
I feel Ganglia and Nagios are good in High Performance Computing environments. But I want to know whether Ganglia and Nagios can be used for Workflows? Can imbed my Scheduling algorithm in a scheduler and use it with Resource Manager over Hadoop MapReduce Framework??
Helpful replies are more appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ganglia and Nagios are monitoring tools, they won't give you a resource management. Checkout the latest Hadoop. It ships with a Resource Management internally.

> The new ResourceManager manages the global assignment of compute
>   resources to applications and the per-application ApplicationMaster
>   manages the application‚Äôs scheduling and coordination.

http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.23.0/